# Tensorflow Saver.save can't write to docker shared volume

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am having a docker container with an Autoencoder that can be started via a Flask-Server. All the scripts are copied into the /root of the Docker and it also gains access to the shared volume /data which looks like this:

/data
-/images
-/models
--/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
--/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.index
--/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.meta
--/checkpoint

and
/root
-MyServer.py

The server can successfully write images into the /data/images folder, but fails to write into the /data/models directory.
I instantiated the tensorflow Saver like this:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

and tried each of the following ways of writing the save-file

```
saver.save(sess, '/data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt')
saver.save(sess, '../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt')
```

Fun fact: it works without errors, when I do this

```
saver.save(sess, './Autoenc.exe.ckpt')
```

but this would write the file to the wrong spot, where it would be deleted on rebuilding the docker container.
When building the docker container and already serving the checkpoints in the mentioned directory, a restore via

```
saver.restore(sess, "../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt")
```

works without any issues..

No let me show you the error message:

```
2018-02-20 15:00:52.868566: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1198] Unknown: ../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate17405837231896083449; Input/output error
2018-02-20 15:00:53.339357: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:277] _0_input_producer: Skipping cancelled enqueue attempt with queue not closed
[2018-02-20 15:00:53,590] ERROR in app: Exception on /train/ [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1329, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: ../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate17405837231896083449; Input/output error
         [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_10, Variable_10/Adam, Variable_10/Adam_1, Variable_11, Variable_11/Adam, Variable_11/Adam_1, Variable_12, Variable_12/Adam, Variable_12/Adam_1, Variable_13, Variable_13/Adam, Variable_13/Adam_1, Variable_14, Variable_14/Adam, Variable_14/Adam_1, Variable_15, Variable_15/Adam, Variable_15/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, beta1_power, beta2_power)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Server.py", line 140, in post
    auto.Do_Autoenc()
  File "/root/dense_autoencoder.py", line 163, in Do_Autoenc
    saver.save(sess, '../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt')
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1593, in save
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1128, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: ../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate17405837231896083449; Input/output error
         [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_10, Variable_10/Adam, Variable_10/Adam_1, Variable_11, Variable_11/Adam, Variable_11/Adam_1, Variable_12, Variable_12/Adam, Variable_12/Adam_1, Variable_13, Variable_13/Adam, Variable_13/Adam_1, Variable_14, Variable_14/Adam, Variable_14/Adam_1, Variable_15, Variable_15/Adam, Variable_15/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, beta1_power, beta2_power)]]

Caused by op 'save/SaveV2', defined at:
  File "Server.py", line 212, in <module>
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 739, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 702, in inner
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 539, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 238, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 232, in handle
    rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 267, in handle_one_request
    return self.run_wsgi()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 197, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 480, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 595, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Server.py", line 140, in post
    auto.Do_Autoenc()
  File "/root/dense_autoencoder.py", line 139, in Do_Autoenc
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1248, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1284, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 762, in _build_internal
    save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 297, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, saveables)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 240, in save_op
    tensors)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1174, in save_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, tensors=tensors, name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3160, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1625, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

UnknownError (see above for traceback): ../data/models/Autoenc.exe.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate17405837231896083449; Input/output error
         [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable, Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam, Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_10, Variable_10/Adam, Variable_10/Adam_1, Variable_11, Variable_11/Adam, Variable_11/Adam_1, Variable_12, Variable_12/Adam, Variable_12/Adam_1, Variable_13, Variable_13/Adam, Variable_13/Adam_1, Variable_14, Variable_14/Adam, Variable_14/Adam_1, Variable_15, Variable_15/Adam, Variable_15/Adam_1, Variable_2, Variable_2/Adam, Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam, Variable_3/Adam_1, Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1, Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6, Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam, Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, Variable_8/Adam_1, Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, beta1_power, beta2_power)]]
```

Please feel free to ask further questions if more information is needed.
Thank you for any attempt of helping, as I am starting to lose my sanity.

Comment: I got a similar error today. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it can permissions for directory '/data/models/'.
Please check container user running *saver* process.

To test, docker exec -it  bash and try to create one file in directory '/data/models/'.